# Royal palaces just outside of major cities?

Tags: europe

I've been planning a cycling holiday in London and wanted to make a short tour to the Royal palace/castle at Windsor.  That got me thinking if other European countries have similar setup of former or current royal residences just outside of major cities?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. There must be hundreds of them -- probably every royal family has a palace near the capital city and many will have several. This kind of big list [doesn't work well in the Stack Exchange format](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: Hampton Court Palace is about 15 miles out of London https://www.hrp.org.uk/hampton-court-palace/visit/getting-here/#gs.HasJsMoX There are several in Scotland, including a palace and a castle at opposite ends of the Royal Mile https://theculturetrip.com/europe/united-kingdom/scotland/articles/top-10-things-to-do-and-see-along-edinburghs-royal-mile/

Comment: There are many royal palaces: the "summer residencies" were often outside cities (but sometime they are now within city limits, like in Vienna). You may adjust the question for the historical period of interest (and so maybe just "castle" of from 1500 to 1800). Karlsruhe has a "nearly royal" palace (also a summer residency), but royal and Germany are not so compatible.

Answer (score 4):

The [Palace of Versailles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_of_Versailles) would seem to qualify. From the Wikipedia article:

> The Palace of Versailles was the principal royal residence of France from 1682, under Louis XIV, until the start of the French Revolution in 1789, under Louis XVI. It is located in the department of Yvelines, in the region of Île-de-France, about 20 kilometres (12 miles) southwest of the centre of Paris.

Answer (score 3):

The [Palácio da Pena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pena_Palace) in Sintra, Portugal, probably counts as being "just outside of" Lisbon. According to the linked Wikipedia article:

> [...] on a clear day it can be easily seen from Lisbon and much of its metropolitan area.

Comment: Palácio Nacional de Queluz qualifies as well and belongs to Sintra .

Answer (score 3):

**Saint Petersburg**, Russia is known for having at least **two** royal palaces in the middle of the city (one hosts [Hermitage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_Palace) and the other is [Engineers' Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Michael%27s_Castle)), as well as **multiple** palaces just outside the city (still within legal boundaries): Konstantin's palace, the most famous [Peterhof palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterhof_Palace), Oranienbaum palace, [Ekaterina's palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_Palace), Paul's palace and Gatchina palace (the only one outside legal boundaries).

Of course there are also quite a few minor palaces situated here and there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not in Europe, but [Iolani Palace](https://www.iolanipalace.org/visit/location-directions-parking/) in Hawaii is located in downtown Honolulu at 364 South King Street, Honolulu, HI 96813. The link above describes its location as,

> Iolani Palace is located in downtown Honolulu, on the corner of King Street and Richards Street. The vehicle entrance to the Palace Grounds is located off Likelike Mall, on the left of King Street between the Palace and the Hawaii State Library.